# Reverse integer in c gives overflow

Tags: c

I am solving reverse integer problem in leetcode in c language.But it gives runtime error on line sum=sum+rem*10;.

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 964632435 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

Here is the code.

```
#define INT_MAX 2147483647
#define INT_MIN -2147483648

int reverse(int x){
    int sum=0,rem=0;
    int p;
    if(x > INT_MAX || x < INT_MIN){return 0;}
    if(x==0){return 0;}
    if(x<0){p=x;x=abs(x);}
    while(x%10==0){x=x/10;}

    while(x>0){
        rem=x%10;

        if(sum > INT_MAX || sum*(-1) < INT_MIN){return 0;}        
        sum=sum*10+rem;

        x/=10;
    }
    if(p<0){sum=sum*(-1);return sum;}
    else{return sum;}
}
```

Comment: `if(x > INT_MAX || x < INT_MIN){return 0;}` How do you expect an integer `x` to be greater than INT_MAX or less than INT_MIN?

Comment: You do see that 964632435 * 10 > 2147483647, right?

Comment: If `x` is `>=0`the variable `p` is used uninitialized

Comment: Remember - not all integer values can be reversed an still fit into an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it gives runtime error on line sum=sum+rem*10;.

To test for potential `int` overflow of positive `sum, rem`, compare against `INT_MAX/10` and `INT_MAX%10` beforehand.

```
    if (sum >= INT_MAX / 10 && (sum > INT_MAX / 10 || rem > INT_MAX % 10)) {
      // overflow
    } else {
      sum = sum * 10 + rem;
    }
```

---

**Handling negatives**

Watch out for `x = INT_MIN` ... `x = -x;`.  That is `int` overflow and *undefined behavior*.

Sometimes it is fun to solve such `int` problems of positive and negative numbers by converting the positive numbers to negative ones [embrace the dark side](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_side_of_the_Force/Legends) - its your only hope. (maniacal laughter)

There are more `int` values less than zero than there are `int` values more than zero - by one.  So `x = -x` is always well defined when `x > 0`.

```
// C99 or later code
#include <limits.h>

int reverse(int x) {
  int x0 = x;
  if (x0 > 0) {
    x = -x;  // make positive values negative, embrace the dark side
  }
  int reversed = 0;

  while (x < 0) {
    int rem = x % 10;
    x /= 10;
    if (reversed <= INT_MIN / 10
        && (reversed < INT_MIN / 10 || rem < INT_MIN % 10)) {
      // overflow
      return 0;
    }
    reversed = reversed * 10 + rem;
  }

  if (x0 > 0) {
    if (reversed < -INT_MAX) {
      // overflow
      return 0;
    }
    reversed = -reversed;
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int x[] = {0, 1, -1, 42, 123456789, INT_MAX/10*10+1, INT_MIN/10*10-1,INT_MAX, INT_MIN};
  size_t n = sizeof x / sizeof x[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Attempting to reverse %11d ", x[i]);
    printf("Result %11d\n", reverse(x[i]));
  }
}
```

Sample output

```
Attempting to reverse           0 Result           0
Attempting to reverse           1 Result           1
Attempting to reverse          -1 Result          -1
Attempting to reverse          42 Result          24
Attempting to reverse   123456789 Result   987654321
Attempting to reverse  2147483641 Result  1463847412
Attempting to reverse -2147483641 Result -1463847412
Attempting to reverse  2147483647 Result           0
Attempting to reverse -2147483648 Result           0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way - which isn't performance optimal but simple - is to convert the integer to a string and then revert the string and then convert back to integer.

The below solution is for **positive** integers - I'll leave it to OP to extend it to handle negative integers.

Could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int reverse(const int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("Handling of negative integers must be added\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char tmp1[100];
    char tmp2[100] = { 0 };
    sprintf(tmp1, "%d", n);
    printf("Input : %s\n", tmp1);
    size_t sz = strlen(tmp1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        tmp2[i] = tmp1[sz-i-1];
    }

    int result = tmp2[0] - '0';
    char* p = tmp2+1;
    while(*p)
    {
        if ((INT_MAX / 10) < result)
        {
            printf("oh dear: %d can't be reversed to int\n", n);
            exit(1);
        }
        result = result * 10;
        if ((INT_MAX - (*p - '0')) < result)
        {
            printf("oh dear: %d can't be reversed to int\n", n);
            exit(1);
        }
        result += *p - '0';

        p++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Output: %d\n", reverse(123));
    printf("Output: %d\n", reverse(123456789));
    printf("Output: %d\n", reverse(1234567899));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input : 123
Output: 321
Input : 123456789
Output: 987654321
Input : 1234567899
oh dear: 1234567899 can't be reversed to int
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not be defining your own values for `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.  You should instead `#include <limits.h>` which defines these value.

Second, this:

```
sum > INT_MAX
```

Will never be true because `sum` can never hold a value larger than `INT_MAX`.  So you can't perform an operation and then check afterward if it overflowed.  What you can do instead is check the operation first and do some algebra that prevents overflow.

```
if ( INT_MAX / 10 < sum) return 0;
sum *= 10;
if ( INT_MAX - rem < sum) return 0;
sum += rem;
```